# Facing issue while installing javaFx

Tags: eclipse

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module helloFX not found

My package is named helloFX and on installing javafx from eclipse marketplace, I get above mentioned error on execution

Answer (score 0):

You can't install JavaFX from the eclipse markteplace. What you are talking about is probably the JavaFX Eclipse plugin which is nice but not actually needed to run a JavaFX program. Go to https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse to learn how to set up JavaFX in Eclipse correctly.